# Add custom customer privacy checkbox in Onepage (billing.phtml)

Tags: checkout, magento-1, customer, onepage-checkout, billing

How can i add 3 custom fields (checkbox) only in billing.phtml using a separate module?

I'm trying to add 3 checkbox into the onepage/billing.phtml page, without modifying the core of magento. I've developed a module in app/code/local with 3 files: 
Model/Entity/Setup.php 
etc/config.xml 
sql/mymodulename_setup/mysql4-1.0.0.php.
These 3 checkboxes should be added to the other to create a new customer account in the db

Comment: Describe your issue in more words. What are you trying to achieve? how should the fields behave? and other info that might be useful.

Comment: I'm trying to add 3 checkbox into the onepage/billing.phtml page, without modifying the core of magento. I've developed a module in app/code/local with 3 files: 
Model/Entity/Setup.php
etc/config.xml
sql/mymodulename_setup/mysql4-1.0.0.php

These 3 checkboxes should be added to the other to create a new customer account in the db.

Comment: What happens with the values? Do you want to check them in JS in PHP? Ignore the values?